How to use function deflateBR across a data frame?
I am trying to deflate a data frame obtained from an API, then using library(deflateBR):
library(sidrar)
pib <-  get_sidra(api ="/t/1846/n1/all/v/all/p/all/c11255/90687,90691,90696,90707,93406,93407,93408/d/v585%200") %>% 
  mutate(data = yq(`Trimestre (Código)`)) %>% 
  select(data, Valor, "Setores e subsetores") %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = Valor,names_from = "Setores e subsetores") %>% 
  mutate("Saldo XM" = `Exportação de bens e serviços` - `Importação de bens e serviços (-)`)

pib_deflacionado <- pib %>%
  filter(data > '2017-12-01') %>% 
  mutate(across(c(`Agropecuária - total`, `Indústria - total`, `Serviços - total`, 
                  `PIB a preços de mercado`, `Formação bruta de capital fixo`,
                  `Exportação de bens e serviços`, `Importação de bens e serviços (-)`, `Saldo XM`), 
                ~ deflate(., nominal_dates = as.Date(`data`), real_date="01/2018",index= "ipca")))

but this code returns the following error:
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `Agropecuária - total`.
Caused by error in `clean_real_date()`:
! 'real_date' must be a character in the MM/YYYY format.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

What could be done?

This is not reproducible I ran your code and it worked without error.
